# help with no exact difference equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this differential equation but I've stuck.

$$
(3x^{2}+y+3x^{3}y)dx+xdy=0
$$

and the integrant factor is $$e^{x^3}$$

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Integrating Factor should be $\mu = x e^{x^3}$.

Comment: I tried to solve the equation with the factor of $e^{x^3}$ , but I get stuck on the part of integration.

Comment: Re arranging I think the integrating factor is $\;xe^{\frac32x^2}\;$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

It seems to me that setting $y=\frac z x$ simplifies the problem since the equation just becomes $$3 x^2 (z+1)+z'=0$$ which is separable and easy to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

The DE can be written as

$$xy'+(3x^3+1)y=-3x^2\iff y'+\frac{3x^2+1}xy=-3x\implies$$

The integrating factor is

$$\int\frac{3x^2+1}xdx=\frac32x^2+\log x\implies \mu(x):=xe^{\frac32x^2}$$

and thus

$$y(x)=\frac{\int-3x^2e^{\frac32x^2}dx+C}{xe^{\frac32x}}$$